# M1 Macbook Air not able to run iPad/iPhone apps

Tags: macos, macbook, iphone, ipad, macos-bigsur

I recently purchased an M1 Macbook and I remember one of the key selling points was being able to open iPad/iPhone apps, this isn't the main reason I purchased it but anyways I was planning to use it in order to play Minecraft Bedrock, a game that I enjoy and that is available for iPad and not Mac, anyways; once I found Mojang had opted out of this and not allowed Minecraft to be downloaded for M1 Macs, I turned to iMazing. Which I used to cmd+c, cmd+v the app on to my Macbook and it was working fine albeit with no keyboard support. However, this morning I logged on and was feeling bored so I opened Minecraft and was greeted with this:

[image]

I am admin and sole user of this machine and all permissions have been granted.

[image]

Can someone please explain why this has occurred? Thank you.

Comment: Precisely which macOS? btw, Pro Tip - If you use Cmd/Shift/4 then tap the space bar, clicking any window will provide a screenshot of just that window, complete with drop-shadow.

Comment: Dear @Tetsujin, Big Sur 11.3.1

Comment: I think sideloading was once again blocked with 11.3 - see https://piunikaweb.com/2021/05/03/macos-big-sur-11-3-update-blocks-sideloading-ios-ipados-apps/ & other references. It's not something i've tried myself, so idk if this is truly 'an answer'.